# How can I put some sprite into Valuemap in cocos2dx v3.7

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I found that the Valuemap is  method. The value don't support pointer. 
But I write those code don't error:

```
Sprite* spriteBg = .....;
Valuemap dic;
dic["abc"] = spriteBg;
```

Error when I get it:

```
for (auto unit:dic){
  Sprite* spritebg = dynamic_cast<Sprite*>(unit.second);
}
```

It show me error "cocos2d::Value is not a pointer"

or other side of this question:
Can I set Ref object into cocos2dx Value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cocos2d::Value type, and by extension Valuemap type are intended to hold values deserialzied from JSON. As such they cannot contain Ref types.

The only built in cocos type I know of that stores cocos2d::Ref derived objects is cocos2d::Vector - which will retain/release members properly, and supports iteration.

---

Ah. @zszen pointed out I missed cocos2d::Map (from `cocos/base/CCMap.h`) which will retain/release the Value type.

```
cocos2d::Map<std::string,Node*> nodeMap;
```

Comment: cocos2d::Vector  and cocos2d::Map has auto release operate

Comment: I think that "cocos2d::Map<std::string,Ref*>" can do any thing in cocos2dx engine. And then create a RefPlus for store Value data. We can put a allowance param.